# how to read mp3 data from google cloud using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to read mp3/wav data from google cloud and trying to implement audio diarization technique. Issue is that I am not able to read the result which has passed by google api in variable response.

below is my python code

```
speech_file = r'gs://pp003231/a4a.wav'
config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    language_code='en-US',
    enable_speaker_diarization=True,
    diarization_speaker_count=2)
audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(uri=speech_file)
response = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
print response
result = response.results[-1]
print result
```

Output displayed on console is

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "a1.py", line 131, in 
print response.results
AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'results'

Can you please share your expert advice about what I am doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its too late for the author of this thread. However, posting the solution for someone in future as I too had similar issue.
Change 
result = response.results[-1] 
to 
result = response.result().results[-1] 
and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the wav file in your bucket? also, this is the entire code? It seems that the sample_rate_hertz and the imports are missing. Here you have the code copy/pasted from the google docs samples, but I edited it to have just the diarization function.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Google Cloud Speech API sample that demonstrates enhanced models
and recognition metadata.
Example usage:
    python diarization.py
"""

import argparse
import io



def transcribe_file_with_diarization():
    """Transcribe the given audio file synchronously with diarization."""
    # [START speech_transcribe_diarization_beta]
    from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
    client = speech.SpeechClient()



    audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(uri="gs://<YOUR_BUCKET/<YOUR_WAV_FILE>")

    config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=8000,
        language_code='en-US',
        enable_speaker_diarization=True,
        diarization_speaker_count=2)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)

    # The transcript within each result is separate and sequential per result.
    # However, the words list within an alternative includes all the words
    # from all the results thus far. Thus, to get all the words with speaker
    # tags, you only have to take the words list from the last result:
    result = response.results[-1]

    words_info = result.alternatives[0].words

    # Printing out the output:
    for word_info in words_info:
        print("word: '{}', speaker_tag: {}".format(word_info.word,
                                                   word_info.speaker_tag))
    # [END speech_transcribe_diarization_beta]



if __name__ == '__main__':

    transcribe_file_with_diarization()
```

To run the code just name it diarization.py and use the command:

```
python diarization.py
```

Also, you have to install the latest google-cloud-speech library:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
```

And you need to have the credentials of your service account in a json file, you can check more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

Comment: Hi Alex, The given code will not work and I tried the same it fails in line result = response.results[-1] with error as AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute 'results'.

Comment: Hello @PP do you have the latest version of the google-cloud-speech library? run `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech` and also, do you have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS json set? look here for more info: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#before-you-begin. Because that code works perfectly for me just editing the variables <YOUR_BUCKET> and <YOUR_WAV_FILE>.

Comment: @AlexRiquelme, All I get when I execute the above code is only one line: "Waiting for operation to complete...
word: 'bye', speaker_tag: 0" Any idea?