# How to read non-text file stored on Google Cloud Storage from Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I need to read a file from Google Cloud Functions. The file I want to read is hosted in Google Cloud Storage. The file is not a text file which prevents me from using things like `download_as_string`.

So far, I have tried reading directly from the object in all of the standard ways `gcs.open(file)`, however gcs was not defined (even though I did import cloudstorage as gcs at the top of the file).

The closest thing I could find was [how to read mp3 data from google cloud using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490557/how-to-read-mp3-data-from-google-cloud-using-python) (I would like to read an MP4 file) but then I tried that, with `blob_uri = gf.open(r'gs://' + bucket_name + '/' + file_name)` I always get the following error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: gs://<yourbucket>/<filename>`

I have also tried `bucket.get_blob(data['name'])`, and `bucket.get_blob(data)`.

Because it is an mp3 file, I cannot open it as a string (such as `file = blobfile.download_as_string()`)

I ahve also tried using requests to attempt to convert the file to bitrate and then read that data however, having to create a new file to open the already existing file was not working correctly due to the Read-Only access Cloud functions requires (I also tried directly uploading to Cloud Storage however because CS returns a blog, I was not able to write to the file).

Is it possible to read directly from the (non-text) file hosted directly on Google Cloud Storage from Google Cloud Functions? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Remember: blob means binaries large object. Thus yes, it's possible to read non string blob!

In Python, you can `download_to_filename` as describe in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python)

Comment: As this is running in Google Cloud Functions, Not Google Cloud Storage, I cannot `download_to_filename` that is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Why you can't ? Is the blob size is larger than 1.5Gb?

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can read a file residing in google cloud storage then to use them generally as a filesystem use the module "gcsfs".
Include gcsfs in your requirements.txt file.

```
import gcsfs
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=projectid)
with fs.open(filename) as filename:
    file = filename.read()
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what have you imported as "gf" but the error you are getting could be either because is expecting a filesystem path or the string is not properly formatted.

Also, you will not be able to download the blob to the filesystem since you cannot write into the disk with Cloud Functions, however you are able to retrieve the blob's binary data process it and upload it again to the bucket.

1.- Getting the [Blob](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.get_blob):

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("my-bucket")
assert isinstance(bucket.get_blob("/path/to/blob.txt"), Blob)
# <Blob: my-bucket, /path/to/blob.txt>
assert not bucket.get_blob("/does-not-exist.txt")
# None
```

Note that the **get_blob** function expects a relative path inside the bucket.

2.- Process your data (remember that will be binary data).

3.- [Upload](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string) the resulting blob to your bucket, you can use the upload_from_string method since the documentation states that it accepts binary data too, but you will have to specify the [**content-type**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) to "application/octet-stream" since the default is "text/plain" and your binary data is technically not "mp3".